# SDWebImage is not loading images from NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, rss

I have a UITableView and I am loading some articles from an RSS file with keys: title, url and image url. I am trying to display the image in the UITableViewCell using the SDWebImage library and when I "load" the image through the dictionary that is downloaded from the RSS the image is not loaded. The url of the image though is loaded successfully and printed exactly before the load. But when I copy the printed url and paste it in another string trying to load that url it works. Below is my code.

```
NSString *urlofimage = [[feeds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey: @"image"];

NSLog(@"%@", urlofimage);

NSString *urlofimage1 = @"https://www.radioevros.gr/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/1495542572-74c82f60669c9db27cad113d22379c72.jpg";

[cell.imageview sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlofimage] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio.png"]
                                   options:SDWebImageRefreshCached];
```

So, my code doesnt seem to be wrong since I was working with the same code before and it was working. In the code above, the urlofimage1 is actually a printed url from the urlofimage. And if I do this:

```
[cell.imageview sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlofimage1] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio.png"]
                                   options:SDWebImageRefreshCached];
```

is working, but if I do this is not.

```
[cell.imageview sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlofimage] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio.png"]
                                   options:SDWebImageRefreshCached];
```

This is loaded inside :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
```

Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: did you check if `[NSURL URLWithString:urlofimage]` is not `nil`?

Comment: Yes it is not nil because all the urls are printed in the NSLog() directly after. That is why I am so confused. Because I can see all the urls successfully loaded. Unless I have to check something else that I didnt understand correctly.

Comment: In your example you are printing `urlofimage` as an `NSString`, not as `NSURL`. Try printing `[NSURL URLWithString:urlofimage]` and see if it is `nil`.

Comment: Yes, it is null. You were right. Why could this be nil? *(null).

Comment: your string could contain invalid characters or you are using the wrong character encoding. Could you somehow show what do you receive exactly?

Comment: What I receive are urls like this: https://www.radioevros.gr/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/1495542572-74c82f60669c9db27cad113d22379c72.jpg. And this is a url that I receive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suspect that you have some invalid characters in your dictionary, like a space at the end or something similar what is hard to spot.

Try encoding your received string first, and than create your `NSURL` instance.

```
NSString *urlofimage = @"https://www.radioevros.gr/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/1495542572-74c82f60669c9db27cad113d22379c72.jpg ";
NSCharacterSet *set = [NSCharacterSet URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet]; 
NSString *endcodedString = [urlofimage stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:set]; 
NSLog(@"%@", [NSURL URLWithString:endcodedString]);
```

**EDIT:**

The encoding highlighted, that there are invalid characters at the end of the URL. Lets get rid of them with the following code:

```
 NSString * urlofimage = @"https://www.radioevros.gr/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/1495542572-74c82f60669c9db27cad113d22379c72.jpg  ";
 NSString *trimmedString = [urlofimage stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]]; 
 NSLog(@"%@", [NSURL URLWithString:trimmedString]);
```

Comment: This encoding is adding at the end of the string the following characters : %0A%09%0A%09%09. And this produces a 404 error. So I think is not working. And I can guess that the url that I receive is already encoded trough the RSS from the Wordpress.

Comment: those are the invalid characters, so it seems you have:
linefeed + tab + linefeed + tab + tab at the end of each URL. These characters should be trimmed.

Comment: Okay, but why since the url that I receive at the beginning is the correct? Why should I encode it since it is valid? I am not sure that encoding is the problem.

Comment: Yes, it is not encoding, but your string is containing invalid characters. I am looking for a solution, i will edit my answer.

Comment: Edited my answer.

Comment: Yes. That works. I am not good at this I guess. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: No worries man, don't beat yourself down. Sweat and hard thinking did not hurt anyone so far :)